# I'm new to angular. I've been trying role based authentication but I keep on getting this error:

Tags: typescript

error TS2345: Argument of type 'Event' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'. here is my code.

```
div class="col-12" style="padding-left: 0;">
   <app-tabs [tabsArray]="tabs" (onTabChange)="tabChange($event)"></app-tabs>
</div>
```

Comment: check the typing of `onTabChange` and `tabChange` they don't have the same paramter type.

Comment: tried changing its not working